# search and display value from database using prompt box in php

Tags: php, database

hai i want to ask how to search and display value from database using prompt box in php.what i  meant is i have button then when user click the button the prompt box will appear and ask for phone number.when user type phone number and click ok, it will search phone number then display it into table so that the user can print..i do not know how to do it..hope somebody can give full example for me...

here my code for prompt box..

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name=myform>
<input type=button value="Try it now" 
onClick="
s=prompt('Enter your Phone Number','Phone');
alert('Hello '+s+'!')">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "hope somebody can give full example" - no we don't write code for you. But are happy to help you write it.

Comment: clearly @jacob did not get the memo :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Once you have gathered the phone number from the user, you will need to make an AJAX request to a PHP file on your server where you pass the PHP file the phone number you have collected, and the PHP file returns whatever information you want to display in whatever format you choose to have it return. For the most part, all of these decisions are entirely up to you.

Some recommendations:

- Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It will make all JavaScript processing easier including DOM processing and AJAX requests.
- If your PHP server has [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), use it as your return format, unless it is more convenient for you to just return a raw HTML string that you can immediately print.

You have not been very clear about exactly what value is being returned from the database, so an example cannot be too exact. However, if you are using jQuery, the following might help you.

**Your HTML File**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(
            function(){
                $( '#mybutton' ).click(
                    function( e ) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var phone = prompt( 'Enter Your Phone Number', '555-555-5555' );
                        $.post(
                            'your_file.php',
                            {
                                phone: phone
                            },
                            function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                                // Instead of alerting this, you should print it,
                                // parse it, or whatever else.
                                alert( data );
                            },
                            'html'
                    }
                );
            }
        );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Try it now" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Your PHP File (your_file.php from the above JavaScript)**

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST[ 'phone' ] ) ) {
    // Do your database processing here, using the phone number passed
    // in by the JavaScript. It is stored in $_POST[ 'phone' ].

    // Then, die() with whatever HTML or JSON or whatever information you are
    // returning.
    die( 'Some HTML to print' );
} else {
    // Error: No phone number posted.
    die( '-1' );
}

?>
```